# python: Process finished with exit code 1 when using PyCharm and PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5

I have three Python(3.4.3) scripts. One of them is for controlling the .ui file generated by PyQt5. When I run the GUI program it accepts all the data and everything and when I press the OK button on an InputDialog the window closes and the console displays.

`Process finished with exit code 1`

When I run the same code on  Python IDLE, it shows:

`<<<<<<RESTART>>>>>>`

This never happenned when I used this same Python(3.4.3 or 2.7) code on Visual Studio. What could be the reason?

Here is the code of the python file controlling the .ui file.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic, QtWidgets
from Email import encrypt_email
from Email import decrypt_email
from Email import newuser

qtCreatorFile = "rsegui.ui" # Enter file here.

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        user, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'New User', 
    'Are you a new user?')
        user=str(user)
        if user in "YESYesyesYy":
            email, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'New User', 
    'Enter Your Email ID:')
            email1=str(email)
            self.sender.setText(email)
            newuser(email1)

    self.encrypt_and_send.clicked.connect(self.EncryptEmail)
    self.decrypt.clicked.connect(self.DecryptEmail)
    self.clear.clicked.connect(self.ClearEncrypt)
    self.clear_2.clicked.connect(self.ClearDecrypt)
    self.sender.setPlaceholderText("Your Email ID")
    self.receiver.setPlaceholderText("Receivers, Separate them by ';'")
    self.subject.setPlaceholderText("Enter Subject")
    self.message.setPlaceholderText("Enter Message")
    self.sender_2.setPlaceholderText("Your Email ID")
    self.message_2.setPlaceholderText("Encrypted Text")



    def EncryptEmail(self):
       sender = str(self.sender.text())
       receiver = str(self.receiver.text())
       receivers = receiver.split(';')
       subject = str(self.subject.text())
       message = str(self.message.text())
       password, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Password', 
'Enter your password:',QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
       encrypt_email(sender,receivers,subject,message,password)

    def DecryptEmail(self):
       email = str(self.sender_2.text())
       message = str(self.message_2.text())
       self.decrypted.setText(decrypt_email(email,message))

    def ClearDecrypt(self):
       self.sender_2.clear()
       self.message_2.clear()

    def ClearEncrypt(self):
       self.sender.clear()
       self.message.clear()
       self.receiver.clear()
       self.subject.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Very good question. Since it deals with code, it might, I think, be a good idea to provide some, don't you think? Furthermore, the traceback would be incredibly useful too!

Comment: I have updated the question with the code. No traceback was printed to the console.

Comment: @N.Wouda any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Well, you are exiting with whatever return code `app.exec_()` sends back (in your case, 1), so I would backtrace it from there. Unless you can post a traceback, I don't have a clue either.

Comment: If you remove everything related to Email module, does it still exit like this? Also, can you post the .ui file?

Answer (score 27):

I have dealt with the same problem, and the answer is twofold:

1. The reason it's crashing could be any number of things. It's probably a programming bug, calling a function that doesn't exist, passing a widget instead of a layout, etc. But since you're not getting useful output you don't know where to look for the culprit. This is caused by:
2. PyQT raises and catches exceptions, but doesn't pass them along. Instead it just exits with a status of 1 to show an exception was caught.

To catch the exceptions, you need to overwrite the sys exception handler:

```
# Back up the reference to the exceptionhook
sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

def my_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    # Print the error and traceback
    print(exctype, value, traceback)
    # Call the normal Exception hook after
    sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys.exit(1)

# Set the exception hook to our wrapping function
sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook
```

Then in your execution code, wrap it in a try/catch.

```
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

Comment: What's the purpose of wrapping app.exec_ in a try-except block?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if it's necessary, but it's how my implementation ended up. Try without, it might not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in pycharm, python 3.8, qt5. The stacktrace was never shown for qt errors inside pycharm; running the file from cmd the error was shown correctly instead.

I solved by doing the following:
open *Edit Configurations* of the file you want to run, scroll down and check the box *Emulate terminal in output console*.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `self.sender.setText(email)`

This is probably causing the problem in my opinion because, "sender" is the name in QObject's function and it does not have any setText attribute, so there may be the problem.

You have to specifically call the widget and setText to it.
For this, you can use instances of the py file of the layout creator.

I had the same issue when I was trying to use this `self.ui.lineEdit().text()`
Here, the problem was -> I was calling the lineEdit function, whereas I had to use it's one attribute.