# What does "Process finished with exit code 1" mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I tried to develop a simple currency program but I have a problem. When I click on `Çevir`, the program should calculate money (like an exchange). But I can't do it. PyCharm writes `Process finished with exit code 1` when I click `Çevir`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import qApp


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
      ....(qtdesigner codes . i skip this part)


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.cevirici)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.cikis)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
   
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Birinci Döviz"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "İkinci Döviz"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Miktar"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sonuç :"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Çevir"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Çıkış Yap"))
    
    def cevirici(self):
        import requests

        import sys

        url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base="

        birinci_doviz = self.comboBox.currentText()
        ikinci_doviz = self.comboBox_2.currentText()

        miktar = int(self.lineEdit.currentText())

        response = requests.get(url + birinci_doviz)

        json_verisi = response.json()


        self.lineEdit_2.setText(json_verisi["rates"][ikinci_doviz] * miktar)
    def cikis(self):
        qApp.quit()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: Process finished with exit code 1 when using PyCharm and PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363552/python-process-finished-with-exit-code-1-when-using-pycharm-and-pyqt5)

Comment: Why doesn't pycharm just show the traceback? The exit code is almost completely useless as a debugging aid.

Comment: The example code will never return from `app.exec_()` and will therefore never call `sys.exit()`. The `AttributeError` will immediately terminate execution of the script. Recent versions of pyqt5 will also call `qFatal()` whenever an unhandled exception is encountered, unless an excepthook has been installed (see [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html?highlight=qfatal#unhandled-python-exceptions)). In these cases, the process exit code will be platform-specific. On linux systems, it is 134 (`SIGABRT`).

Comment: I found [this pycharm support thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000176210-Print-Process-finished-with-exit-code-1), which suggests setting the "Emulate terminal in output console" option might show a proper python traceback instead of the useless exit code message.

Comment: @BSekili. `miktar = int(self.lineEdit.text())`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`0` and `1` are exit codes, and they are not necessarily python specific, in fact they are very common.

`exit code (0)` means an exit without errors or issues.

`exit code (1)` means there was some issue / problem which caused the program to exit.

The effect of each of these codes can vary between operating systems, but with Python should be fairly consistent.

Answer (score 9):

`0` and `1` are exit codes.

`exit code (0)` means an exit without an errors or any issues, can be a compile time error or any dependency issue.

`exit code (1)` means there was some issue which caused the program to exit. For example if your program is running on `port :8080` and that port is currently in used or not closed, then you code ends up with `exit code 1`

Answer (score 0):

Scroll up in your run screen of pycharm.
A bug problably printed the exit exception somewhere in the middle of your printlines. This makes it look your program ran normally and suddenly exit with code 1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).